# javascript validation is not working inside the add more button of modal box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I Have the modal button which contain the form and that form contain the **add more button** which add the fields.The problem is **validation is not working** inside the add more button.

Below is my code:
**index.php**

```
<a href="new_user_popup.php" style="color:white" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info new_entry_btn" style="margin-left:0%">
       New Entry
     </button>
    </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#trigger').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  return false;
})

});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({width:'auto',
                               height:'auto', 
                              'max-height':'100%'});
});
</script>

<div class="container">


    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
**new_user_popup.php**

        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-24">
            <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
                 <button class="add_field  btn " onclick="incrementValue()" style="margin-left: 443px;">Add</button>
                 <div>
                 <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" ></div>
        </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">


     $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID

    var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
              x++; //text box incrementa

              $('<div style="margin-left:50%;"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="selectbasic" style="margin-left:-220px;">Type of work</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="type_of_work[]" name="type_of_work[]" class="form-control" style="margin-left:17%;width:222%"><option value="Option one">Audit Report</option><option value="Option two">ITR filing</option><option value="Option three">VAT Filing</option><option value="Option four">Accounting</option><option value="Option five">Registration</option><option value="Option six">Certification</option><option value="Option seven">Others</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic" style="margin-left:-29%">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status11' + x + '" name="status[]" style="width:210%;margin-left:-1%;" class="form-control"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label" style="margin-left:-15.5%;";">DATE</label><div class="col-8"><input class="form-control datepicker pick" id="datee' + x + '" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['date'] ?>" style="width:86%;margin-left:10.6%;margin-top:-10%;" type="text" readonly></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput" style="margin-left:-36%">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comments11' + x + '" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" style="width:342%;margin-left:20%"></div></div></center><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left: 197px; margin-top: -40px;position:absolute"><img src="images/del24.png"></a></a></div>').insertBefore(add_button) //add input box        
     var newInput=$("#datee"+ x).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
          newInput.datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
          $("#status11" + x).click(function () {

            if ($("#status11" + x).val() == "Completed") {
                $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", "required");
            }
            else
              $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", false);
        });

      }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

    $(wrapper_pre1).on("click",".remove_field_pre1", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is auto generated trying using $(document) most of the time:

Change This

```
 $("#status11" + x).click(function () {

            if ($("#status11" + x).val() == "Completed") {
                $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", "required");
            }
            else
              $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", false);
        });

      }
    });
```

TO:

```
 $(document).on('click',"#status11" + x,function () {

            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "completed") {
                $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", "required");
            }
            else{
              $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", false);
            }
    });/
```

//it should be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">


     $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID

    var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click

        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
              x++; //text box incrementa

              $('<div style="margin-left:50%;"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="selectbasic" style="margin-left:-220px;">Type of work</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="type_of_work[]" name="type_of_work[]" class="form-control" style="margin-left:17%;width:222%"><option value="Option one">Audit Report</option><option value="Option two">ITR filing</option><option value="Option three">VAT Filing</option><option value="Option four">Accounting</option><option value="Option five">Registration</option><option value="Option six">Certification</option><option value="Option seven">Others</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic" style="margin-left:-29%">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status11' + x + '" name="status[]" style="width:210%;margin-left:-1%;" class="form-control"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label" style="margin-left:-15.5%;";">DATE</label><div class="col-8"><input class="form-control datepicker pick" id="datee' + x + '" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['date'] ?>" style="width:86%;margin-left:10.6%;margin-top:-10%;" type="text" readonly></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput" style="margin-left:-36%">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comments11' + x + '" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" style="width:342%;margin-left:20%"></div></div></center><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left: 197px; margin-top: -40px;position:absolute"><img src="images/del24.png"></a></a></div>').insertBefore(add_button) //add input box        
     var newInput=$("#datee"+ x).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
          newInput.datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
      }
  });


     $(document).on('click',"#status11" + x,function () {

            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "completed") {
                $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", "required");
            }
            else{
              $("#comments11" + x).attr("required", false);
            }
    });


    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

    $(wrapper_pre1).on("click",".remove_field_pre1", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

    </script>
```

Comment: This logic is also not working do you have any other idea@razzbee

Comment: remove the validation part from  $(add_button).click(function(e){ })

Comment: yes, the html in the js is causing the problem, format it very well

Comment: i have modal name new entry .when i click on modal the form popup which contain add button which dynnamically add fields.the javascript is not working inside add button@razzee